# Why the file encoding type is null?

Tags: python, encoding

I'm having a problem with my files, I downloaded a file from a backup I had but when I open it in VSCode I get an error on my screen: The file is not displayed in the editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding. I check the encoding type with a small python script:

```
import chardet
import glob

print('')
print("File".ljust(45), "Encoding")
for filename in glob.glob('./*.js'):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as rawdata:
        result = chardet.detect(rawdata.read())
    print(filename.ljust(45), result['encoding'])
```

These are the results:

> ```
> File                                          Encoding
> .\index.js                                    None
> .\test.js                                     ascii
> ```

I created a new JS file "`test.js`" to check that script works and... yep, it's working and the `index.js` file is "broken" or "corrupted" (the encoding).

Is there any possibility to "fix" the enconding type and be able to open it?

Comment: Add `len(rawdata.read())` to your output. I guess zero for `index.js`?

Comment: Yeah, the output is zero